# FontAwesome icon prop error in Nextjs project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, icons, font-awesome

I have Nav bar component where I am trying to insert FontAwesome icon but it is saying: Type "icon" is not assignable to type 'IconProp'.

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

    export Nav = () => {
    
    return (
<ul>
       <li>My Profile <FontAwesome icon="fa-solid fa-right-from-bracket" /></li>
    </ul>
)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to import the Icon Definitions.

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faLocationDot } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

// usage -->
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faLocationDot} />
```